# Automatically Hanging and Black Screen [No Return]

Tags: release-freya

Let me first give my laptop's description, it is:

- **Model: HP Compaq 6710s**
- **Processor : Dual-Core Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T7100 @ 1.80GHz**
- **Memory: 2.4GB**
- **Graphics: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c)**
- And I have just installed **Elementary OS 0.3 64bit on it**.

My problem:

It seems, whenever I am doing some heavy work, here just using chrome and opening 4-5 tabs along with playing youtube video, my OS just freezes and I am shown a black screen, upon which no button works and I just have to restart the computer manually.

Can someone please help me figure out what is happening wrong here and how to fix it.

I understand the info is quite inadequate to predict the correct error but I am willing to post any other info required but please explain me as I am newbie to Linux.

Comment: Although I can't really pinpoint your problem, chrome is a really heavy browser (very memory intensive). With only 2.4GB and 64 bit system maybe some leak is causing a system freeze? Can you see if it takes more tabs to freeze your PC with firefox or midori?
Experimenting with html5 instead of flash player could also prove insightful. Other examples of heavy work would also help

Comment: @JohnGuerreiro I tries `free -mt` and what I am getting after opening 5-6 tabs on chrome is tha the free memory reduced to only 85 out of 2497 where as free swap is 1825 out of 1905....can this be the problem? But I thought linux can be used in less memory devices too and minimum requirement of the elementary is 512MB !!? Anyway is there some solution to this other than increasing my memory?

Comment: Elementary itself does not ship google chrome, so the requirement is 100% correct. Your expectations are incorrect here. if chrome uses up all your free memory - use another browser. That would be the solution

Comment: @V_Pavel Using firefox or other browser instead of chrome just pospond the hanging, When I am opening a lot of software, it's again hanging and the black screen is shown. My problem is, how to resume my work when I get the black screen without restarting the laptop.

Comment: probably by switching to another console (Ctrl+Alt+F<X> where X is some number between 1-7 which would work for you). Log in using the console, find application that's consuming all your memory (with "top" for example) and kill it. "It's simple. We kill Batman" (c) Joker

Comment: If you can get to a VTT via `ctrl+alt+f1` immediately after the freeze try `less /var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `less /var/log/syslog` to check the xserver or system logs to search for clues. You can do it after a reboot as well, just you'll have to scroll back from the bottom a bit to find the time when the freeze occured.

Comment: Or post them up to pastebin and link to it in your question with the time the freeze occurs and someone else might be able to diagnose it.